# FileInputStream throws no such file or directory exception- Firebase rest API user auth

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to make authentication calls to the Firebase Realtime Database REST API, following this tutorial: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/user-auth

```
GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("cmov.json"));
GoogleCredential scoped = googleCred.createScoped(
    Arrays.asList(
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/firebase.database",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    )
);
scoped.refreshToken();
String token = scoped.getAccessToken();
```

I have this code on my login activity in Android Studio, and for some reason I always get an exception - open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) - when trying to read the "cmov.json". I have the file inside "assets" folder that I've created, and when I try to delete the file I get a usage warning asking if I'm sure I want to delete the file, so I assume I'm reading from the correct path in the code. Why is FileInputStream throwing a no such file or directory exception?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assets are files on your development machine. They are not files on the Android device.

[Use `AssetManager` and `open()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/AssetManager.html#open(java.lang.String)) to open an `InputStream` on your asset, not `FileInputStream`.

If and when you do start working with actual files on the device, never just pass some string to `File` or `FileInputStream` constructors. Use proper methods to derive the filesystem path for [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) or [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(new FileInputStream("cmov.json"));
```

You need to replace that with the following:

```
AssetManager assetManager = getApplicationContext().getAssets();
GoogleCredential googleCred = GoogleCredential.fromStream(assetManager.open("cmov.json"));
```

If the file is in `assets`, even thought Android Studio makes it seem like it's linking to the file when you type it, it won't be found because `FileInputStream` means it's looking for a file on the Android device.  Your JSON file is technically within the APK.

Note: What I do is, check for that file in app's internal storage and if it's not there, copy it. Next time user open the application, file will be there and it won't be copied. This way, it's easier to access the file as well as file is available on Android device if needed.